# capistrano cannot restart application with passenger

Tags: rvm, capistrano, passenger

i have a rails 6 / ruby 2.7.2 app, and the passenger gem, app is working great in prod, but cap deploy chokes at the end with

```
  01 *** ERROR: Phusion Passenger(R) doesn't seem to be running. If you are sure that it
  01 is running, then the causes of this problem could be one of:
  01
  01  1. You customized the instance registry directory using Apache's
  01     PassengerInstanceRegistryDir option, Nginx's
  01     passenger_instance_registry_dir option, or Phusion Passenger(R) Standalone's
  01     --instance-registry-dir command line argument. If so, please set the
  01     environment variable PASSENGER_INSTANCE_REGISTRY_DIR to that directory
  01     and run this command again.
  01  2. The instance directory has been removed by an operating system background
  01     service. Please set a different instance registry directory using Apache's
  01     PassengerInstanceRegistryDir option, Nginx's passenger_instance_registry_dir
  01     option, or Phusion Passenger(R) Standalone's --instance-registry-dir command
  01     line argument.
```

The only help I can find seems to be for the non-gem installation of passenger, i installed passenger and made these mods to the /etc/apache2.conf as the installer indicated:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/passenger-6.0.10/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
 PassengerRoot /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/passenger-6.0.10
 PassengerDefaultRuby /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/wrappers/ruby
</IfModule>
```

Passenger / apache seem to be working fine, i just cannot restart the app from capistrano.

Thanks for any help,
Kevin